# iOS AR(Kit) Development

Tags: windows, ios, xcode, unreal-engine-4, augmented-reality

Я решил сделать ARKit проект для iOS на Windows, а потом скомпилировать его через Mac OS на виртуальной машине, но у меня появляется эта ошибка:
https://uengine.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=67350

Кто-нибудь знает как её решить?

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]: Я нашел решение: нужно обновить Mac OS и XCode до последней версии - если у вас VirtualBox, то установите вместо него VMWare, т.к. в VirtualBox невозможно обновить Mac OS (На данный момент у меня 11 XCode и 10.15.2 Mac OS Catalina)